# Building errors after updating CocoaPods libraries

Tags: ios, build, xcode6, cocoapods

I'm working on a legacy iOS project as a newbie. After I updated the CocoaPods and libraries, I've got these weird errors after building the project which never happen before.

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods-Model
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods-Model is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

And here is my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

link_with ['DianaViewModels']

pod 'AVOSCloud', '~> 3.0'
pod 'PixateFreestyle'

target :Model do
  link_with ['DianaModels']

  pod 'ReactiveCocoa',    '~> 2.2'
  pod 'TMCache',          '~> 1.2'
  pod 'SSKeychain',       '~> 1.2'
  pod 'Mantle',           '~> 1.3'
  pod 'AFNetworking',     '~> 1.0'
end

target :Test do
  link_with ['DianaTests']

  pod 'Kiwi',             '~> 2.2'
end

target :View do
  link_with ['Diana']

  pod 'SVPullToRefresh',  '~> 0.4'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD',    '~> 0.7'
  pod 'SWTableViewCell',  '~> 0.1'
  pod 'MTMigration'
  pod 'Masonry'
  pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
  pod 'NJKWebViewProgress'

  target :ViewDebug do
    link_with [
      'DianaDev',
      'DianaViews'
   ]

    pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK'
  end
end
```

By the way, I'm using the CocoaPods plugin in the Xcode. But a lot error are output when I check the **Install Docs during integration**:

```
Error opening xar archive: /var/folders/3x/mgl299js6k13tlrspqv21n340000gn/T/Model-ReactiveCocoa.xar
```

Are there some wrong configurations in my CocoaPods or Build Setting in Xcode6.3? Thanks for your help!

ADDED:
Here's my **Link Binary With Libraries** in the **Build Phases**. Does the red item mean something is wrong? It looks like this is the cause.
[image]

Comment: Have you re-run `pod install`? the linking error is because the project is trying to add the Model pod (defined for the Model target) but can not find the binary.

Comment: yes, i've re-run `pod install` several times but it doesn't work.